# Is there a closed form of this integral $ \int_0^\infty \sin(xe^{-x})dx\, $?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have tried by subsititution method and it got more  complicate than before.

Can anyone help me to evaluate this integral.

> $$
> \int_0^\infty \sin(xe^{-x})dx\,.
> $$

Comment: I should be surprised by a closed form.

Comment: Maple doesn't find a closed for solution. Still interessted if someone finds a closed form :).

Comment: Does a series count as a closed form?

Comment: They are nice answers of course I accept them. I am new to this site, I am still trying to understand how this site work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there exists a closed form in terms of some special known functions. One may recall that the following standard power series
$$
\sin u = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} u^{2n+1}, \quad u \in \mathbb{R},\tag1
$$ has an infinite radius of convergence allowing us to obtain
$$
\int_0^\infty \sin(xe^{-x})\:dx=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} \int_0^\infty x^{2n+1}e^{-(2n+1)x}dx \tag2
$$ the latter integral may be evaluated by using the classic integral representation of the Euler $\Gamma$ function,
$$
\int_0^\infty x^{2n+1}e^{-(2n+1)x}dx=\frac{(2n)!}{(2n+1)^{2n+1}}, \tag3
$$ we then obtain

> $$
> \int_0^\infty \sin(xe^{-x})\:dx=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n\quad}{(2n+1)^{2n+2}}.\tag4
> $$

The convergence of the preceding series is very fast. One gets, using *Mathematica*,

```
NSum[(-1)^n/(2 n + 1)^(2 n + 2), {n, 0, \[Infinity]},  WorkingPrecision -> 50]

0.98771814780760758564289940276054141639545399170883
```

One gets that $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \sin(xe^{-x})\:dx>0$, and that the numerical value is not far from $1$ as could be guessed by approximating the initial integral with $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty xe^{-x}\:dx=1.$

Comment: Why are they closing this page. The answer is beautiful

Comment: @adambui I'm afraid a closed form might not exist. Maybe you can accept this answer. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I was new to the site and i didn't what to do. Your answer is excellent and neat, tidy and elegant